# How do I remove a function from overload resolution?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to have an instance of my class convert to an `int` when using the assignment operator. So I wrote this code:

```c++
struct X
{
    X() = default;
    X& operator=(int) { std::cout << "operator=(int)\n"; return *this; }
    operator int() { return 0; }
};

int main()
{
    X a, b;
    a = b;
}
```

But it does not get called. This is because it's calling the implicit copy-assignment operator which is an exact match for the argument. I want my code to call the conversion operator on `b` first and then have the `int` return value bind to `operator=()`.

Is there a syntax to tell the compiler "do not consider this function"? In other words, how do I remove a function from overload resolution?

I've tried using templates on the copy-assignment operator so I could do SFINAE but I guess that just creates another function so the non-template one is always going to be a better match.

Comment: Nope. You can make it an error to call something (by `delete`ing it) but you can't remove something altogether.

Comment: You could just cast it explicitly `a = static_cast<int>(b);` This would also be more intuitive behavior for someone else looking at your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implicitly created assignment operator stays the best version even if you `= delete` it, i.e., you'd get an error instead of another version being chosen. I would recommend simply forwarding the logic as appropriate and not bother trying to remove the function:

```
X& X::operator= (X const& other) {
    return (*this) = static_cast<int>(other);
}
```

Admittedly, this potentially allows an extra implicit conversion sequence which may not otherwise be allowed:

```
T -> X -> int
```

To counter this possibility, you'd add another assignment operator:

```
template <typename T>
X& X::operator= (T&& other) {
    int arg = other;
    return (*this) = arg;
}
```

Comment: I tried marking the assignment operator `private`, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Thanks but I think I'll stick with the cast from the outside like Praetorian said. For users of my code the copy-assignment operator will do very unexpected things. :)

Comment: @japreiss Overload resolution happens before access control so whether a function is private, protected or otherwise is not considered.

Comment: What do you mean by "extra" implicit conversion sequence? Where have I permitted a conversion from `T` to `X`?

Comment: @templateboy: I'm not saying you do. However, my point is, if there is a conversion from some `T` to `X` but _not_ from `T` to `int` the copy assignment effectively allows assigning a `T` via the a conversion to `X`. That may not be desirable and the assignment operator deducing the rvalue will prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

for preventing compiler to create default function you must declare theme private(note that you do not need to define theme).
for more info,i suggest to you that read effective c++ by scot Meyers chapter 2,item 6.

Comment: Even if I declare them private that won't change how overload resolution works. It will still choose the regular copy-assignment operator rather than the overloaded one.

Answer (score 0):

Just write

```
a = static_cast<int>(b);
```